# Using open (unix) on a string

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I'm trying to use open, which is described as such in the man pages:

`int open(const char *pathname, int flags);`

So I'm calling it like this:

```
int fd = open(filename.c_str(), O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
if(fd == -1)
{
    perror("There is something wrong with open: ");
}
```

where filename is a string that was converted from a char array. More specifically:

```
string filename = string(&a2[0], 1024);
```

where a2 is a char array of size 1024.

The perror I'm getting is that the file does not exist, which is strange since I have O_CREAT as one of my flags.

I greatly appreciate any help! Also, this is my first post, so if you require more info/better formatting, please let me know!

EDIT: Fixed a few typos, sorry everybody! I am using a string, but I'm using the c_str function with it, so it does compile. Accidentally left that out in my initial post, along with another typo.

Comment: Is that the real code, only it doesn't look like it should even compile ?

Comment: It should be `int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT);`

Comment: Several issues:  Extra ')' following the '|' (or) operator in the function call.   Secondly, `open` requires a `char*` as the filename, you're supplying a `string`, which is NOT the same.  Perhaps you could use `filename.c_str()`... but a c++ string is not the same as a c 'string'.

Comment: `perror(filename.c_str())` provides a far more useful error message.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page carefully; error cases include

> ```
>    ENOENT O_CREAT is not set and the named file does not exist.  Or, a
>           directory component in pathname does not exist or is a
>           dangling symbolic link.
> ```

```
   ENOENT pathname refers to a nonexistent directory, O_TMPFILE and one
          of O_WRONLY or O_RDWR were specified in flags, but this kernel
          version does not provide the O_TMPFILE functionality.
```

So if you `open` something like `bad/path/foo` (and `bad/path` does not exist), even with `O_CREAT` it will fail. (You need to call, perhaps several times, [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html), e.g. on `bad` then on `bad/path` as the [mkdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) command do with `-p` ...)

See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find what syscalls your program is using with which arguments.

You should always test syscalls like `open(2)`  for failure and then use `errno` or `perror`

Of course, `open` does not want a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/); use its [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function to get the `const char*` C-string inside.

BTW, you should compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. Putting a breakpoint on your `open` call would be faster than asking on StackOverflow.

Is your `a2` array properly initialized? What is its value? Check with the debugger! I would initialize

```
 string filename(a2);
```

But you could just pass directly `a2` to `open`

Comment: I tried passing my char array (a2) to open, but it wasn't working. Here's how I built my char array: `char a2[1024] = {0}; for(int d = pos+1; d < 1024; d++) { a2[d] = str[d]; }`

Comment: You really should use the debugger.

Comment: @Tingles that would result in a non-terminated unless `str[]` is (a) also 1024 chars wide, and (b) has a terminator at or before str[1023]. Further, it is outright undefined behavior if `str[]` is not *at least* 1024 chars wide and `a2[]` is not *at least* `pos + 1024 + 1` chars wide. Now write a stand-alone code listing with a `main()` that reproduces your *real* problem and post it in your question. Guessing what code you're not showing us and having to pry it out line at a time is not productive.